# Regular Expression find space delimited numbers

Tags: regex, expression, match

I have a string that comes from user input through a messaging system, this can contain a series of 4 digit numbers, but as users are likely to type things in wrong it needs to be a little bit flexible.
Therefore I want to allow them to type in the numbers, or pepper their message with any string of characters and then just take the numbers that match the formats

```
=nnnn or nnnn
```

For this I have the Regular Expression:

```
(^|=|\s)\d{4}(\s|$)
```

Which almost works, however as it says that each group of 4 digits must start with an =, a space, or the start of the string it misses every other set of numbers

I tried this:

```
(^|=|\s*)\d{4}(\s|$)
```

But that means that any four digits followed by a space get matched - which is incorrect.

How can I match groups of numbers, but include a single space at the end of one group, and the beginning of the next, to clarify this string:

```
Ack 9876 3456 3467 4578 4567
```

Should produce the matches:

```
9876
3456 
3467 
4578 
4567
```

Comment: you need to use assertions `(?:^|[=\s])\K\d{4}(?=\s|$)`

Comment: What language/regex library?

Comment: It was C#, although I though that RegEx was (pretty much) language agnostic - is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to use lookarounds which won't consume any characters.

```
(?:^|[=\s])\K\d{4}(?=\s|$)
```

OR

```
(?:^|[=\s])(\d{4})(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fT5cX6/3)

Your regex `(^|=|\s)\d{4}(\s|$)` fails because at first this would match `<space>9876<space>` then it would look for another space or equals or start of the line. So now it finds the next match at `<space>3467<space>`. It won't match `3456` because the space before `3456` was already consumed in the first match. In-order to do overlapping matches, you need to put the pattern inside positive lookarounds. So when you put the last pattern `(\s|$)` inside lookahead, it won't consume the space, it just asserts that the match must be followed by a space or end of the line boundary.

Comment: Please explain why it works, for people like me who want to understand the regexs they blindly copy/paste.

Comment: Marked as the answer for the explanation, which I understand, but I still find RegEx next to impossible to read, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\d+\b
```

`\b` asserts position at a word boundary (`^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W`). It is a 0-width anchor, much like `^` and `$`. It doesn't consume any characters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/23)

or

```
(?:^|(?<=[=\s]))\d{4}\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL4sU9/1)

Comment: Someone didn't read the whole post! `Therefore I want to allow them to type in the numbers, or pepper their message with any string of characters and then just take the numbers that match the formats`